# jQuery drag and drop issue for remove link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm having three div's in my page for drag and drop, 
In first div (drag 1) contain "Remove" link. 
after drag the first div(drag 1) to first droppable div. 
i can able to remove the first div(drag 1). 
after remove the (drag 1), i can't able to drag the 
second div (drag 1) same first droppable div

My Code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXDhE/91/)

```
.
```

Comment: so u want to remove all and not just div 1

Comment: That is not a issue. Once i removed the "drag 1" div, the second div & third div  i mean "drag 2" and "drag 3"  can't able drag to the first droppable div

Comment: @naresh Did u checked my answer

Comment: Yes. its working fine. one more help. when i remove the dragged div, the text "drop here" should be display on "droppable" div. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NXDhE/93/)

try this

```
$('.draggable').draggable({ revert: true });
drop();
function drop()
{
   $('.droppable').droppable({
      hoverClass: 'active',
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).html(ui.draggable.remove().html());
        $(this).droppable('destroy'); 
      }
   });
}


$(".droppable").on("click", "a", function (){        
     $(this).closest('.cs-drop').fadeOut(200, function(){$(this).remove();});   
     drop();
 });
```

Comment: Amazing. one more help. when i remove the dragged div, the text  "drop here" should be display on "droppable" div. is this possible?